# Portal for ArcGIS license within ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-10.3, license, arcgis-portal

I have arcGIS 10.3 and have 100 users portal for ArcGIS, I want to use the portal for ArcGIS but I don't know how. I installed Portal for ArcGIS and it still keep telling  the software is not licensed

Comment: If you have a license then you have support, your best bet (other than Komla answer below) is contacting your Esri support rep who will be able to get you up and running in no time and ensure you have the right number of named users in your Portal.

Answer (score 4):

After installing portal you need to authorize it, separately from authorizing ArcGIS Server.  This can be done by going to the start menu in windows server, selecting ArcGIS -> Portal for ArcGIS 10.3 -> Software Authorization.  This will start the software authorization process and it will prompt you to authorize over the internet or select authorization file.